# Concurrency and Coordination Runtime (CCR) Learning Resources

Tags: resources, ccr

I have recently been learning the in's and out's of the [Concurrency and Coordination Runtime (CCR).](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb905450.aspx)
Finding good learning resources for this relatively new technology has been quite difficult.

(A quick google search brings up "Creedence Clearwater Revival" as the top result!)

Some of the resources I have found:

- [Free e-book chapter](http://www.robochamps.com/rc/data/learningarea/141076-cover-df.pdf) from WROX on the Robotics Developer Studio
- [Good Article/post](http://www.infoq.com/articles/Using-CCR) on InfoQ
- [Robotic's Member blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/pollrobots/archive/2008/07/22/ccr-utilities-part-1.aspx)
- Very active [MSDN CCR Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/roboticsccr/threads/) - Got plenty of help from here!
- [Great MSDN Magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/magazine/cc163556.aspx) by Jeffrey Richter
- Official [CCR User Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb905450.aspx) - Didn't find this very helpful
- Great [blogging series](http://iodyne.blogspot.com/) on CCR
- iodyner [CCR Related Blog](http://iodyne.blogspot.com/) - Update: [Moved to here](http://iodyner.spaces.live.com/)
- Eight or so [Videos](http://channel9.msdn.com/tags/CCR/) on Channel9.msdn.com
- [CCR Patterns page](http://channel9.msdn.com/wiki/ccrpatterns/) on MS Robotics Studio - I haven't read this yet
- 4 x [CCR Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ccr) on Stackoverflow - Most of the questions have been Mine! LOL
- [CCR and DSS toolkit](http://blogs.msdn.com/msroboticsstudio/archive/2009/04/22/rds-2008-standard-edition-and-ccr-and-dss-toolkit-2008-available-on-msdn.aspx) has now been released to MSDN Members

Do you have any good learning resources for the CCR?

I really hope that Microsoft will publish more material, so far it has been too Robotics specific.  I believe that MS needs to acknowledge that most people are using the CCR in issolation from the DSS and Robotics Studio.

### Update

The Mix 2010 conference had a presentation by Myspace about how they have used the CCR framework in their middle tier.  They also open sourced the code base.

- [MySpace DataRelay](http://datarelay.codeplex.com/)
- [Mix Video Presentation](http://live.visitmix.com/MIX10/Sessions/EX04)

Comment: Looks like you've got a pretty comprehensive list - were you not able to find what you were looking for after exhausting it?

Answer (score 1):

- [Licensing](http://blog.aheil.de/2007/08/08/TheMicrosoftRoboticsStudioLicensingModel.aspx)
- [CCR PowerPoint presentation](http://igor.moochnick.googlepages.com/ccrpresentation1)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Robotics Studio 2008 R3 is now available and now free for everyone to use.

Get it here http://www.microsoft.com/robotics/ or directly here http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=c185a802-5bbe-4f28-b448-aefe63a7eff7

Comment: Great news! and Great decision MS

Answer (score 0):

We recently completed a project using DSS (Built on top of CCR). It seemed to be a great framework. One issue we had was going from 32bit to 64bit which meant all threads were duplicated.

(Dev was done on a 32bit Mac using Vista. Deployment on Win08 64bit)

I'd suggest the DSS tutorials as a nice way to see how the CCR lib's can be used within that environment.

Comment: Sorry - it meant each thread would run twice. So when we had a thread writing 'Hello World' it would write 'Hello World' twice.

Comment: I am not particularly interested in diving into the DSS world just yet.  Learning the CCR is quite enough effort :)

Answer (score 0):

[3 posts series](http://www.lnbogen.com/Part1SpawnEnumeratorDealingWithBillionsOfIndependentItems.aspx)