# java disruptor library c# analog

Tags: c#, performance, .net-4.5, hft

I'm writing HFT software.

[Disruptor](http://code.google.com/p/disruptor/) claims to be a "high performance inter-thread messaging library", and apparently offers substantial performance improvements.

Is there something with comparable speed for .NET?

Comment: Which performance problems have you encountered with your current code?

Comment: @L.B HFT is kind of software which always encounter performance problems no matter what :) I know that all Java HFT programmers use "disruptor" without "measuring" if they have performance problem. Why not using something that 100+ times faster?

Comment: Explain what you mean by "fast" please. You say it is faster than what you have, what do you have? You say it's so fast everyone must use it, why "must" they use it? Please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sam already said, disruptor has been ported to dotnet you'll see more on [GitHub Disruptor Net](https://github.com/odeheurles/Disruptor-net)

I was thinking of your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10206624/how-to-execute-50-parallel-methods-500-times-per-second-effectively/10206889) from yonks ago the other day around how I'd approach it today knowing what I now know about concurency (large number of threads = [bad](http://gwan.com/)).

There are a few patterns you could use here,

1. Single threaded for maximum throughput and lowest latency.  Run side by side procesess and do some form of sharding to getting additional throughput per core.  Think ala [Redis](http://redis.io/topics/benchmarks)
2. A non-blocking algorithm ala CAS
3. [Disruptor](http://disruptor.googlecode.com/files/Disruptor-1.0.pdf) / [CCR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525154/concurrency-and-coordination-runtime-ccr-learning-resources)

I am personally curious enough to work on a few examples if you've got any to find what works best when.

There is an overview technical paper you should have a flick through by [Disruptor](http://disruptor.googlecode.com/files/Disruptor-1.0.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

There is a [C# port](https://github.com/odeheurles/Disruptor-net) but as has already been said it should only be used to solve specific problems. Its not a silver bullet to make your software faster. Do you have the perf tests to see if it changes anything? Does your current architecture fit the disruptor model of discreet workers?

Comment: answer to all questions is "no". it seems i just want to have "silver bullet" if it exists.